# How to use another template engine in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to create an engine that i will later use when working with Template instances.

I do not want to define it in the settings due to the fact that the logic defined in it should not be distributed everywhere, but only in specific cases.

Here's what I did:

```
from django.template.engine import Engine


class ModelEngine(Engine):
    def find_template(self, name, dirs=None, skip=None):
        # some another logic to get a template instance
        ...

engine = ModelEngine()

# Usage
template_code = "{% include \"some_template.html\" %}"
Template(template_code, engine=engine).render(Context())
```

Is this solution correct? Is there something wrong with not inheriting from BaseEngine, but from Engine? If yes, please advise something.

Comment: Uhh, _why_ do you want to make a template engine, exactly? "_# some another logic to get a template instance_" is it to find the templates as this comment of yours implies?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am making a tool for sending emails and the template is in the form of a Django model so that everything does not have to be redeployed every time, as is the case with file templates. But this approach has a drawback: if you need to use template inheritance, for example, then the default template search is not suitable. I am overriding find_template to look for instances in the database.

Comment: Have you considered that rather than overriding the engine itself, all you need is a [Custom loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#custom-loaders)? Also there is a package that already does what you want: [django-dbtemplates](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbtemplates)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you. Give an answer, I will make it a solution. And one more thing, how can I use my loader exactly when I need it?

Comment: Django will try each loader in order until it finds a template, so you can allow it to work itself in case you aren't expecting any clashing template names. If you aren't sure about that on the other hand I would consider simply prefixing these template names such that they won't clash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the *template engine* just to load the template from some other place is not needed. Instead all you need is a [custom loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#custom-loaders). Below is some sample code for a loader that may fit your needs:

```py
from django.template import Origin, TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.template.loaders.base import Loader

class DBLoader(Loader):
    def get_template_sources(self, template_name):
        yield Origin(
            name=template_name,
            template_name=template_name,
            loader=self,
        )
    
    def get_contents(self, origin):
        try:
            # Assuming name of your model and field that has template name
            instance = YourTemplateModel.objects.get(template_name=origin.template_name)
            return instance.content
        except (YourTemplateModel.MultipleObjectsReturned, YourTemplateModel.DoesNotExist):
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)
```

Next you can simply add this loader to your `TEMPLATES` setting to use it:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'path.to.DBLoader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Note that there is also a package out there named [django-dbtemplates](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbtemplates) that already does this, and it is likely more efficient than this basic implementation here.